# Embedding SDL window into GTKMM window

Tags: c++, sdl-2, gtkmm3

Excuse a bit of code. I am afraid it is necessary. I am embedding an SDL window inside a GTKMM window as follows:

```
HelloWorld::HelloWorld()
: _button("Test") 
{
  set_border_width(10);
  add(_vbox);

  _button.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &HelloWorld::on_button_clicked));

  _vbox.add(_button);
  _vbox.add(_eventbox);
  _eventbox.add(_socket);

  _vbox.show_all();
}

void HelloWorld::on_button_clicked()
{
  int tx = 0, ty = 0, tw = 0, th = 0;
  _eventbox.get_window()->get_geometry(tx, ty, tw, th);

  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  SDL_QuitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_EVENTS); // We need no events.

  // Plug SDL window inside GTKMM's socket.
  if ((_sdl_window = SDL_CreateWindowFrom((const void*)_socket.get_id())) == NULL) {
      std::cerr << "Window creation error.\n";
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  _renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(_sdl_window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE | SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE);
  _texture  = SDL_CreateTexture(_renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, tw, th);

  // Draw red rectangle on texture.
  SDL_SetRenderTarget(_renderer, _texture);
  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(_renderer, 255, 0, 0, 0);
  SDL_RenderClear(_renderer);

  // Blit it.
  SDL_SetRenderTarget(_renderer, NULL);
  SDL_RenderCopy(_renderer, _texture, NULL, NULL);
  SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(_sdl_window);
}
```

Running this shows the GTKMM window. When the button is pressed, the SDL window appears below it and the red fills the texture.

Now: if the mouse is not moved inside the red area, all seems well.  But if I move the mouse inside the red area, i.e., in the SDL window, then after a few seconds the SDL window just disappears.

I can see no obvious reason why this happens. Does someone know where my embedding of the window might be wrong, or what is likely to cause this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to listen for redraw event (GTK's "expose-event", I suppose) and behave accordingly. Drawing once isn't going to last.

Comment: I received the expose events, but omitted that code here for brevity. A bit more digging revealed the following: the Gtk::Socket loses its anchor, when the mouse pointer is moved in its area. It seems, if I add the SDL window directly into the Gtk::EventBox instead of the Gtk::Socket, then it draws, receives expose events properly, etc. Only, when I try to close the SDL window, SDL_DestroyWindow(), SDL hangs forever. So, I'm not really sure if one should try and make the Gtk::Socket thing work, or try and find out why SDL_DestroyWindow() hangs...

Comment: Gtk::Socket is for using [xembed](https://standards.freedesktop.org/xembed-spec/xembed-spec-latest.html) and needs something like Gtk::Plug to work. `SDL_CreateWindowFrom` takes xid. It's something different.


I would suggest investigating the hang (does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945700/gcc-sdl2-hangs-indefinitely-and-stops-responding help?)